# How is it possible to generate a pdf of swagger data?

Tags: java, pdf, swagger

In our project, [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) generates `.json` files to store the 
structure of the REST-ful service.

With programms like swagger-ui, it is possible to view the 
structure of the REST-ful service 
and even interact with it.

But how is it possible with swagger to generate a document of the 
files that can be printed(e.g. in `.pdf` format)?

Comment: I think you have to use a third party library like apache in order to generate pdf, as far as I know swagger don't do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several tools that can allow you to do that, among a few:

- [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen)
- [Swagger2Markup](https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup)